# IfError isn't catching type type mismatch error vba

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am getting a type mismatch error on the line of code below.  It is inside a loop, and the error doesn't occur until the first iteration where `.Cells(rowStart + i, ISO_revs_col).Value` is a string.  It makes sense that this would cause an error, but I would expect the `.IfError` function to just return the "0" string.  If anyone can tell me why I am getting an error instead of "0" I would appreciate it.

```
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(CLng(.Cells(rowStart + i, _
                                        ISO_revs_col).Value), "0")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is an *IFERROR* in worksheet function available in VBA. Not sure though, no way to check atm. But you can use *On Error Resume Next* and *On Error Goto 0* instead.

Comment: As noted, you cannot use `IFERROR` in that manner. In the past I've kludged my way through with something like `Application.Sum(.Cells(rowStart + i, ISO_revs_col).Value))` since the `SUM` worksheet function will total text strings as zero.

Comment: There is a worksheet function (I found it on Microsoft's help), but as noted below I was using it wrong. @Jeeped I think I will use your solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @nateAtwork yep there is, but not in VBA as I pointed in my comment. Jeep's solution is clever not using `CLng`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IFERROR is a worksheet function, and will detect worksheet errors. The following error types are evaluated: #N/A, #VALUE!, #REF!, #DIV/0!, #NUM!, #NAME?, or #NULL!.

Type mismatch (runtime error 13) is a VBA error, not a worksheet error.

To handle VBA errors, you need to use the VBA error handling routines.  So something like:

**EDIT:** to trigger on other errors:

```
On Error Resume Next
    'your looping routine start
x = CLng(.Cells(rowStart + i, ISO_revs_col).Value)
select case err.number
    case 13
       x=0
       err.clear
    case <> 0
       msgbox "Error " & err.number & vbTab & err.description
 end select
debug.print x
    'your looping routine end
on error goto 0
```

The above won't tell you where the error occurred, so you might want to just wrap the single line as:

```
on error resume next
x = CLng(.Cells(rowStart + i, ISO_revs_col).Value)
if err.number = 13 then x = 0
on error goto 0
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you for explaining it.  I'm hesitant to use this for my current loop though because it is rather large and I don't want to miss errors elsewhere in the loop.  I will definitely use it in the future though.

Comment: @nateAtwork Then instead of clearing the error, just test to see if there is another error; or only have it in effect when that one statement is being executed, instead of for the entire loop.

Comment: That definitely solves it, I didn't realize you could put it inside the loop.  Thanks again.